# Getting vuejs to render in nodejs/express app

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, render

I have a nodejs/express js app. It is a simple 4 page mainly text site at the moment.

I added vuejs with npm and tried to mount it

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

It does not render but the output gives

```
<!--function (a, b, c, d) {
    return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true);
  }-->
```

CanI use vuejs with node and if so how do I get it to render out.

Edit: the html (rendered from .pug)

```
<div class="content"><!--function (a, b, c, d) {
    return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true);
  }--><p>hello</p></div>
```

.pug file

```
extends layout
block content
  div#app {{message}}
```

Comment: can you paste html?

Comment: There is an <div id="app">{{ message }} </div> in there but it seems to get stripped out and the comment put in it's place.

Comment: Vue is generally used on the client side (iirc there is a way to do server side rendering too... but probably not for what you're doing).  You can package that up with node, serve it separately with Nginx, etc...  How are you serving up that page?

Comment: I am using expressjs

Comment: Sure but I  mean how are you using express to serve up your pages?  You can either serve up static html pages or render them with pug (which it sounds like you're doing)  Can you show a snippet of the pug files?  Are you serving up the Vue.js statically?  Or using browserify/webpack to build it for the client?

Comment: Can you paste the snippet of Pug you've written? So we can see what's the problem more clearly.

Comment: Sorry it is pug.